# How can i get the velocity of a rigidbody moved by a joint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've working in a project where i have 2 objects.
One is moved by editing the position with (Transform.position)
and the other has a Spring Joint attached with the first.

The idea is the second object will follow the first BUT if the movement is to tiny the second object will change his color.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you understand how to do this with physics? If not I recommend trying the Physics stack exchange for more info or google.

Comment: Can't tell exactly what you're asking for from the above description but to shed a little light, you might try looking at it from a physics perspective as suggested above. You could try this example: Force = Mass*Acceleration so if you were trying to figure it out You know the force and mass since joints inherit from rigidbody which has a mass variable. So you solve for acceleration which is velocity/time. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want, you want to change the color of the second object according the velocity of that object *in relation to* the velocity of the first.

So, at a certain point in the loop (`FixedUpdate` method, probably), you will measure the magnitude of the difference between the velocities:

```
var diff = (gameObject1.rigidbody.velocity - gameObject2.rigidbody.velocity).magnitude;
```

(or user sqrMagnitude for performance)

After that you'll just probably need to normalize `diff` to be inside the interval `[0;1]` where `0` is no difference in velocity and `1` is a huge difference, and then multiply that by the color.